# How to dispatch coroutines directly to main thread on the JVM?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I'm setting up a kotlin coroutine based networking framework for the jvm. The Client and Server classes implement CoroutineScope, and the override for coroutinecontext is Dispatchers.IO, as I am pretty sure that's the correct Dispatcher to use for such a case. However, I wish to handle read packets on the main thread, or at least provide that option. Without reading the documentation, I used Dispatchers.Main, which I now realize is for the android UI thread. Is there a dispatcher I can use to get a coroutine running on the main thread? If not, how would I go about making one?

I have looked around the kotlin documentation on how to create a dispatcher based around a single thread, but I couldn't find anything besides newSingleThreadContext which creates a new thread. I also figured out that it is possible to create a dispatcher from a java Executor, but I'm still not sure how to limit this to a already existing thread.

```
class AbstractNetworkComponent : CoroutineScope {
    private val packetProcessor = PacketProcessor()
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext = job + Dispatchers.IO
}

class PacketProcessor : CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext = job + Dispatchers.Main //Android only!
    private val packetHandlers = mutableMapOf<Opcode, PacketHandlerFunc>()

    fun handlePacket(opcode: Opcode, packet: ReceivablePacket, networker: Writable) {
        launch(coroutineContext) {
            packetHandlers[opcode]?.invoke(packet, networker)
        }
    }
}
```

So with the Dispatchers.Main I get an IllegalStateException due to the android component missing. Is there a way to create a dispatcher that blocks the main thread until its completion (like runBlocking does?) Thanks!

Comment: In what environment are you?, for your question I suspect is not Android, is JavaFx?? Swing??

Comment: Ah yeah that’s kinda important; this is just a generic java application. Currently I’m running tests off of a main function, but the goal is for this to be a networking api for the jvm. No javafx or swing is going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`runBlocking` is exactly what you need. It creates a dispatcher and sets it in the coroutine context. You can access the dispatcher with

```
coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor] as CoroutineDispatcher
```

and then you can pass it to an object that implements `CoroutineScope` or whatever else you want to do with it. Here's some sample code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.IO
import kotlin.coroutines.ContinuationInterceptor

fun main() {
    println("Top-level: current thread is ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    runBlocking {
        val dispatcher = coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor]
                as CoroutineDispatcher
        ScopedObject(dispatcher).launchMe().join()
    }
}

class ScopedObject(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) : CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext = Job() + dispatcher

    fun launchMe() = launch {
        val result = withContext(IO) {
            "amazing"
        }
        println("Launched coroutine: " +
                "current thread is ${Thread.currentThread().name}, " +
                "result is $result")
    }
}
```

This will print

```
Top-level: current thread is main
Launched coroutine: current thread is main, result is amazing
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. If I were to put that runBlocking bit inside the ScopedObject and grab the context there, would it just use the thread the object was created on?

Comment: `runBlocking` dispatches to the thread it's called on. But since it's the low-level machinery that creates an environment for coroutines to run in, I don't see it as good design to have it inside an object that is the client of this environment.

Comment: How to convert this code from a tutorial: `val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())` without using Dispatchers.Main? I tried to use `Dispatchers.Main`, in a plain Kotlin console project, for testing, just as this OP, and I could not avoid runtime error that Dispatchers.Main does not exist.

Comment: @DamnVegetables `Main` is defined only for GUI environments. If you're writing just top-level example code, you'll probably use the `Default` dispatcher, which you don't even have to specify. You may also want to use `runBlocking`, which creates its own dispatcher and uses it to run the coroutine within its body.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Guide to UI programming with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#guide-to-ui-programming-with-coroutines) **kotlinx.coroutines** has three modules that provide coroutine context for different UI application libraries:

- [kotlinx-coroutines-android](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android) -- Dispatchers.Main context for Android
  applications.
- [kotlinx-coroutines-javafx](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-javafx) -- Dispatchers.JavaFx context for JavaFX UI
  applications.
- [kotlinx-coroutines-swing](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-swing) -- Dispatchers.Swing context for Swing UI
  applications.

Also, UI dispatcher is available via `Dispatchers.Main` from **[kotlinx-coroutines-core](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core)** and corresponding implementation (Android, JavaFx or Swing) is discovered by ServiceLoader API. For example, if you are writing JavaFx application, you can use either `Dispatchers.Main` or `Dispachers.JavaFx` extension, it will be the same object.

Comment: I saw that guide but "import kotlinx.coroutines.javafx.JavaFx as Main" says "Unresolved reference: javafx". But I do have kotlin-coroutines core 1.3.3 in my dependencies, just the javafx part is missing somehow.

Comment: I guess you need to add `kotlinx-coroutines-javafx` module to dependencies.

Comment: Thanks I found it on search.maven.org and it worked