# Coroutine, No Android, Module with the Main dispatcher is missing

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to test Coroutine in Kotlin console project in IntellJ. I have added this library: org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.0. It worked, until I used `Dispatchers.Main`. After adding it, it threw a runtime exception.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main);
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    scope.launch {  }
}
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android' and ensure it has the same version as 'kotlinx-coroutines-core'

I switched the library with `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0` as existing answer suggested, but then it threw a different runtime error.

> NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Looper

Seems like that the library is for Android. Is using 'kotlinx-coroutines-android' the correct solution for Kotlin console project? If not, how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Clearly, you can't use the android version on non-android target. As the docs say: "Core modules of kotlinx.coroutines are also available for Kotlin/JS and Kotlin/Native." In your case you probably want some variety of native - all the popular Posix like targets seem to be supported.

Comment: Or possibly the plain JVM one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194735/1731626

Comment: @oakad I said I was using `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.0` before switching to the android version. The one you linked is the same thing as I was using, isn't it? Does the code above runs without a runtime error with that library in your Kotlin console project in IntellJ?

Comment: @Sergey The linked answer mentions three things: android, javafx, and swing. Those all seem to be GUI thing. I am using Kotlin console project. You know, a project that has nothing but a `println("hello world")`. Does it mean that it has to be a GUI project to use Dispatchers.Main? The answer also mentions "...-core", but that thing was I was using and it caused the runtime error above.

Comment: So it seems `Dispatchers.Main` is intending for UI applications. If your app doesn't have UI it can't use `Dispatchers.Main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dispatchers.Main` is most likely not what you want here. It is intended to dispatch coroutines on the main event loop in GUI applications.

**For console applications**, and especially in the kind of snippet you're sharing here, you probably instead want to use the main thread (in which `main()` in executed) as the event loop, and prevent `main()` from returning until coroutines are done. This is done by using `runBlocking`, which blocks the current thread for outside code, but uses it as an event loop for the `CoroutineScope` passed as `this` to the lambda that you pass to `runBlocking`.

So your code should likely look like:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope

        // there is a CoroutineScope here, the receiver is implicit
        launch {
            // this code will run in the main thread,
            // concurrently with other coroutines and other code
            // in the runBlocking lambda
        }
        // this code will run in the main thread,
        // concurrently with the launch and other coroutines
    }
}
```

---

**If you did have a GUI application**, you could check the [KDoc for Dispatchers.Main](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-main.html) to see which dispatcher is used depending on your target platform. **If you target the JVM, you will need an extra dependency** to bring the dispatcher that corresponds to the UI technology you use. This is also described in the KDoc:

> In order to work with the Main dispatcher on the JVM, the following artifact should be added to the project runtime dependencies:
>
> - `kotlinx-coroutines-android` — for Android Main thread dispatcher
> - `kotlinx-coroutines-javafx` — for JavaFx Application thread dispatcher
> - `kotlinx-coroutines-swing` — for Swing EDT dispatcher

Answer (score 4):

`Dispatchers.Main` is intended for GUI applications, it is not supported for the console project.
As per [Guide to UI programming with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#guide-to-ui-programming-with-coroutines) **kotlinx.coroutines** has three modules that provide coroutine context for different UI application libraries:

- [kotlinx-coroutines-android](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android) -- Dispatchers.Main context for Android
  applications.
- [kotlinx-coroutines-javafx](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-javafx) -- Dispatchers.JavaFx context for JavaFX UI
  applications.
- [kotlinx-coroutines-swing](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-swing) -- Dispatchers.Swing context for Swing UI
  applications.

Use [`runBlocking`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) to suspend `main` function until coroutines are executed:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking { ... }
```

Comment: People seeing this error while using Compose for Desktop -> they can use the `kotlinx-coroutines-swing` version. You can double check your stacktrace, to confirm which exact version you should use

Answer (score 0):

Import kotlinx-coroutines-swing:(your kotlin using version) in your dependencies gradle and compile the program

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing:$kotlin_coroutines_version"